# Adding a syntax group to ALL syntaxes

Tags: vim

I want to add a syntax group to all syntaxes. Namely, I want to highlight characters like `+,-,*,/` and other punctuation chars for every programming language. I know that I can add a `<language>.vim` file for every language to my `.vim/after/syntax` folder, but I want to make this generic. Currently I have to create one such (exactly the same) syntax addendum file for every programming language, and that's... inelegant.

Basically I'd like to place an `all.vim` file in `.vim/after/syntax` and have the contents of that file added to every syntax file. I'm fairly sure that this option doesn't exist (I checked the vim docs), so I'm looking for some way to emulate that. Is there perhaps a programmatic way of adding the new syntax group to every syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply place it in your vimrc.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I added both the new syntax command and the highlight command in my vimrc, but it doesn't seem to affect anything. I tried putting them both before and after the `syntax on` command. But if I place the syntax command in the `after/syntax/lang.vim` file for some lang and the `hi` in my colorscheme file, then the commands work as expected. I'm on gvim in Linux Mint 11.